# Open a website with proxy setting-Java

Tags: java, selenium

Is there a way to open a website say google.com with proxy setting.
In one of the forum I found below code.
But when browser comes up it takes default firefox setting i.e no proxy.
It seems Runtime wont work.

How can I launch a website using the set property

In one of the forum I found :
System.setProperty("proxySet", "true")
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "myproxy")

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use WebDriver2, you could create FirefoxProfile with suitable preferences:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", "1");
profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.http", "<proxy_ip>");
profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.http_port", "<proxy_port>");
FirefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```